# Display current Time (now) in real time inside outputtext

Tags: primefaces, time, real-time, taglib

Is there a ready UI component which displays,in outputtext, the current time/date .

Really, i search on this feature, and i don't found anything.

We search :

- [here](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/)

and

- [here](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/views/home.jsf)

Unfortunately, Nothing !

We want something like this

```
<p:outputtext>
   <p:timer date="now" format="hh:MM:ss" realtime="true" />  
</p:outputtext>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is component called clock in primefaces, it will display current time in either Client or server mode.

```
<p:clock/>
<p:clock pattern="HH:mm:ss dd.MM.yyyy" />
```

*autoSync* parameter will syncs time periodically.